# Cookie Creation in Symfony2 prod environment.

Tags: symfony, cookies, session-cookies

I am testing cookies creation. In development mode everything works well, but in production mode it fails to create cookies. I am using symfony2. Do I need to do any changes in production mode for cookie creation.

Comment: I don't think so. Any log in app/logs/prod.log ?

Comment: Hi, in dev mode, every time it uses app_dev.php like http://xxx/app_dev.php/. And this will clear cache on every call to system. But in prod mode it won't, is this could be a problem. Also I checked log file there is no messages.